# How to replace mocked function with another function where I can assert based on the received arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am trying to mock test a function call inside a function call of a class based on the StreamHandler logging class. Inside this class, a function is called that will make a `requests.post` call if the error level is CRITICAL. I want to test that `requests.post` call.

Here is the logging class:

from logging import StreamHandler
import logging
from lib.api import API

```
class ApiLogHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, api: API) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._api = api

    def emit(self, record) -> dict:
        if(record.levelno == logging.CRITICAL):
            try:
                # the first parameter is `message`, the second is `level`
                return self._api.send_log_message(self.format(record), record.levelno)
            except:
                pass
```

And here is my test case:

```
import logging
import sys
from os import path, pardir
from types import SimpleNamespace
from unittest import mock, TestCase
# Required to allow import of same-level files.
sys.path.append(path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)), pardir)))

from lib.api import API
from lib.api_log_handler import ApiLogHandler
from models.configuration import Configuration

fausse_configuration = {
    "url": "http://test-site-who.cares",
    "token": "asdfasdfasdf",
    "location": "test-site1",
    "client_type": "client",
    "organization_name": "stackoverflow"
}

class TestApi(TestCase):
    def fake_post(self, url: str, data: dict, headers: dict):
        self.assertIn("This is a test message", data['message'])
        self.assertEqual(data['level'], logging.INFO)   # This should fail the test, it doesn't.
        self.assertEqual(True, False)                   # This should fail the test, it doesn't.
        reponse = SimpleNamespace(json=lambda : {}, status_code=200, content="blahblahblah!")
        return reponse

    @mock.patch('models.response.isinstance', return_value=True)
    def test_message_logging(self, mock_isinstance):
        test_config = Configuration(fausse_configuration)
        api = API(test_config)

        logging.basicConfig(
            datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-8s - %(threadName)-18s - %(message)s',
            handlers = [
                ApiLogHandler(api)
            ],
            level=logging.DEBUG,
            force=True
        )

        with mock.patch('lib.api.requests.post', wraps=self.fake_post):
            logging.critical("This is a test message")
```

Right now I am able to `print` inside the `fake_post` function so I know it's been called. However the assert statements inside it are never run, as the test passes and it should fail.

I also tried assigning the fake_post to `mock.side_effect`, but the assert statements still don't work properly.

Is there a way to call assert statements with the `unittest` module in a function that is not itself a method of TestCase? Or am I simply using the wrong approach and I should go about this in a different way?

Comment: Sorry for being "that guy", but are you _sure_ you need this setup and can't just use (or at least subclass) the built-in [`HTTPHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#httphandler)?

Comment: As for your question, I see no `requests.post` call in your `ApiLogHandler` class, only this `self._api.send_log_message` call. Sure, you don't want to just test that instead? If the method behind that is your own code, then unit testing best practices suggest you test _that_ separately. In general, your test seems very far from isolated. Typically unit tests should actually test _units_, whereas you seem to be testing a bunch of functions all at once here.

Comment: I think `HTTPHandler` was discarded because we need to do a lot of preprocessing before sending an API request. But you're right on the bigger point, I should not try to test both units during a single unit test. I should test that `ApiLogHandler.emit` calls the `send_log_message` and I should test independently that `send_log_message` passes the right arguments to `requests.post`. 

Thanks for your help!